# Anchor tag in Pdf using itextsharp and c#

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to create an anchor tag to the text in the pdfcell, so when clicked, it should jump on to the target page within the pdf document.

Below is the code I am using.

```
oCell = new PdfPCell();

string text = "Target Page";

Anchor anchor = new Anchor(text, fontBody);

anchor.Reference = "#Target";

oCell.AddElement(new Phrase(anchor));
```

It's only displaying text as "Target Page", but there is no hyperlink to the text.

Comment: Hi All, Just a quick note, The document I am generating here is a PDF/A document, I guess that's the reason why hyperlinks are disabled. Is it possible to enable hyperlinks on a PDF/A document?

Comment: You only show that you create an anchor referencing `#target`. Do you also have an anchor named `target`?

Comment: Yes I have one on the same page as..... anchor.Name= "Target";